# Transforming a sesquilinear form into an inner product?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inner-products

I know that a vector space equipped with a seminorm can be transformed into a normed space by taking the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation $f \sim g$ iff $\|f-g\| = 0$.

Can a similar procedure be applied to make a vector space equipped with a positive [sesquilinear form](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sesquilinear_Form) into an inner product space? If so, what is the associated equivalence relation one should take? Simply $f \sim g$ iff $\langle f-g,f-g\rangle = 0$?

Comment: An inner product is a positive-definite Hermitian sesquilinear form. If your sesquilinear form is already positive then it's already true that $\langle x, x\rangle = 0 \implies x = 0$ so your quotient is trivial. You're also missing the condition $\langle x, y\rangle = \overline{\langle y, x\rangle}$. You also need to check that your quotient has a vector space structure.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I was thinking about an inner product of the form of an integral. For example, $\langle f,g\rangle = \int \overline{f(x)}g(x)w(x)dx$ for some real-valued weight function $w$. This obviously satisfies $\langle f,f\rangle \ge 0$, but then it would only imply $f = 0$ almost everywhere, right? How does it ensure $f = 0$ without the quotient construction?

Comment: I would have assumed by "positive sesquilinear form" you meant positive-definite, but if you mean positive-semidefinite then yes you would need to take care of this with your quotient.

Comment: Also, "positivity" doesn't make much sense without the Hermiticity condition to begin with. In that sense, if what you have already is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian sesquilinear form, then yes the only thing you need to do is force definiteness with the relation $f \sim 0 \iff \langle f, f\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff okay, this makes a lot of sense! Thanks!